# All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes)

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin

i got this popup

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 25.3.1, 25.0.2, 24.0.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1 and com.android.support:renderscript:25.0.2

over this line

> compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

in app:gradle

The dependancy list on gradle is

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-4.0.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/mobihelp.jar')
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.+'         //plan to remove
    compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:6.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.freshdesk:hotline-android:1.0.15'         //plan to remove
    compile 'com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:4.+@aar'
    compile 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.+'
    compile 'se.emilsjolander:android-flipview:1.1.0'
    compile 'org.florescu.android.rangeseekbar:rangeseekbar-library:0.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.bugsnag:bugsnag-android:3.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/joda-time-2.9.9.jar')
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

Comment: use latest libraries, do you have support-r47 package?

Comment: @rupinderjeet nope

Comment: You are going to need to generate a Gradle dependency report, find out what libraries are requesting what `com.android.support` dependencies, and manually request those same dependencies with `25.3.1`.